# Query within IF after a WHILE won't return any results

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to execute a query but it doesn't go through and I can't figure out.
Kind of new to functions so I am not sure if I am messing something up there.

```
$n = 0;
$qr=$Classy->queryF("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_status != 3 ORDER BY user_id");
if ($Classy->fetchN($qr) > 0) {
   while ($data = $Classy->fetchF($qr)) {
      $n = $n + 1;
      echo $data['username']."<br>";
   }
} else {
   echo "No users";
}
```

And here are the functions:

```
class Classy
{
  function queryF($setQuery) {
    $conn = $this->connection;   // This works correctly btw..
    $query = $conn->query($setQuery);
    return $query;
  }
  function fetchF($setFetch) {
    $row = $setFetch->fetch();
    return $row;  
  }
  function fetchN($setFetch) {
    $row = $setFetch->fetchColumn();
    return $row;  
  }
}
```

The IF statement works correctly but the while does not output anything while being under IF. If I remove IF/ELSE statement the while works correctly as long as there is a user to show. Any idea what I've done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: fetching a record from a resultset will move the cursor forward. Or other said: you can't fetch the same record twice.

Comment: The question is, why there is fetchN()? Or, for that matter, why there is Classy at all. What gives?

Comment: @HonkderHase Ah that makes sense. I was just trying to combine them two so I can echo something when there are no results available. Thanks!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was trying to check if there are any results so I can either proceed and show them or echo a message that there are none available. That Class is way bigger I was just showing some specific parts of it here. Thanks

Comment: You should learn about separation between data manipulation and presentation logic. Your data manipulation should never output anything. Add a function that returns a **array**,  [and then use this array for output](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/d59acba0e8a76bc53d2869a730a7b6f8/).

Comment: By the way, the naming is absolutely horrendous, all those $qr and fetchN will drive anyone nuts. Also, I suspect that all other methods of this class are as useless as those posted here. I bet that Classy class offers **much worse** experience than vanilla PDO

Comment: `was trying to check if there are any results`... https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php should help you

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you for the information and all. These are actually the only "useless" functions in there. To be honest, I thought it would be a "cleaner" look instead of going vanilla PDO.

Comment: Cleaner? Vanilla PDO is [just two lines](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/02bb19bbbb94c79c66ac6f2a24fdf860/)